# If $A\subsetneq X, B\subsetneq Y$, X,Y are connected then $X\times Y- A\times B$ is connected

Tags: general-topology

Question is to prove that :

If $A\subsetneq X, B\subsetneq Y$, and  $X,Y$ are connected then $X\times Y- A\times B$ is connected.

I do not immediately see why this is true.

So, I thought if i can easily see something less is true. i.e., if $X$ is connected and $A$ is a proper subset of $X$, Then $X-A$ is connected.

take $X=\mathbb{R}$ ,and for $a\neq b$, $A=[a,b]$ then $X-A=\mathbb{R}-[a,b]$

we have $\mathbb{R}-[a,b]=(-\infty,a)\cup (b,\infty)$

$(-\infty,a)\neq \emptyset$ and $(b,\infty)\neq \emptyset$ and $(-\infty,a)\cap (b,\infty)=\emptyset$

somehow i have to say that $(-\infty,a)$ and  $(b,\infty)$ are not open in $\mathbb{R}-[a,b]$

for $M\subset X$ we say that $U$ is open in $M$ if $U=V\cap M$ for some open set $V$ in $X$

Suppose $(-\infty,a)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}-[a,b]$ then

we would have $(-\infty,a)=\mathbb{R}-[a,b] \cap V$ for some open set $V$ in $\mathbb{R}$

but $(-\infty,a)=\mathbb{R}-[a,b] \cap (-\infty,a)$ and $ (-\infty,a)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ thus,

$(-\infty,a)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}-[a,b]$  similarly, $(b,\infty)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}-[a,b]$

I do not see where did i go wrong??

Please help me to sort this out..

thank you.

P.S : Though  my original question is to prove $X\times Y- A\times B$ is connected. while writing this, i was thinking of trying some thing less which i thought could be easily seen and then try for original question... but, I got stuck with simple thing only... But I feel "$A\subsetneq X, B\subsetneq Y$, and  $X,Y$ are connected then $X\times Y- A\times B$ is connected." then $A\subsetneq X$ , $X$ is connected then $X-A$ should also be true... please let me know why is this false.. I mean it should be... right???

Comment: Your second statement does not follow from the first, and is in fact not true, as you have shown. The first statement is, however, true. To see why, notice that there exists a point in $X\times Y- A\times B$ that does not belong to A or B, and remember that connected components are disjoint or equal(this does not immediately prove the statement, there are another couple of steps).

Comment: what does it mean to say a point in $X\times Y -A\times B$ that does not belong to $A$ or $B$... a point in $X\times Y$ is a orderd pair where as $A$ or $B$ is just set of elements.. no ordered pairs :O

Comment: @Peter : this question is not even similar to that... I am asking if some thing less is true... my preference is not to see whether $X\times Y -A\times B$ connected or not but does it implies $X-A$ is connected... please do not see that in other way...

Comment: Sorry, corrected in my answer.

Comment: Note that $(X \setminus A) \times (Y \setminus B) \neq (X \times Y) \setminus (A \times B)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposition that "given $A\subsetneq X$ where $X$ is connected, then $A-X$ is connected" is not true, as you shown, but it does not follow from or is required for the original proposition, witch is true. To see why, notice that there exists a point $(x, y)$ in $X\times Y−A\times B$ where $x$ is not in $A$ and $y$ is not in $B$, and remember that connected components are disjoint or equal (this does not immediately prove the statement, there are another couple of steps). it might help you intuition to imagine $X=Y=[0, 1]$ thus, $X\times Y$ can be seen as a square, now imagine different $A$ and $B$'s.

Elaboration (edit):

let $x_1\in X-A$ and $y_1\in Y-A$

it is enough to show that any point $(x,y)\in X\times Y-A\times B$ is in the same connected component as $(x_1, y_1)$

let $(x,y)\in X\times Y-A\times B$,

without loss of generality $x\notin A$ so,

$\{x\}\times Y\subset X\times Y-A\times B$

$\{x\}$ is connected and $Y$ is connected so $\{x\}\times Y$ is connected and thus $(x, y)$ and $(x, y_1)$ belong to the same connected component.

in the same way $X\times \{y\}$ is connected and $(x, y_1)$ and $(x_1, y_1)$ belong to the same connected component.

This out line is a bit rough, and should be polished, but you can get the general idea.

Edit:

as a response to the P.S, your second proposition is not weaker then the original, to put it very unmathematically , in a 2 dimensional space you can go around an obstacle, cutting a segment out of a road will split it into separate parts, but cutting a rectangle out of a parking lot will live it connected(so long as the rectangle does not span the whole width or height of the lot, thus $A\subsetneq X$ and not $A\subset X$)...

Comment: I am not able to conclude anything from "(x,y) in X×Y−A×B where x is not in A and y is not in B, and remember that connected components are disjoint or equal".. could you please elaborate that a little.. I see that connected components are either disjoint or equal but what does that mean anything in this case.. please help me..

Comment: Thank you for your response for my P.S :) I am a bit relaxed now.. :)